# how to access session scope instances in ZKoss

Tags: java, session, mvvm, scope, zk

```
main.zul

    ...@init('Main')...
        <zk>
        ...
           <include src="north.zul"/>
           <include src="@bind(vm.pageSource)"/>
        ...
        <zk>
```

---

```
north.zul
    ...@init('North')...
        <zk>
        ...
           <a onClick="@command('linkClicked')">link</a>
        ...
        <zk>
```

---

```
Main.java
...
private String pageSource = "content1.zul"
//getter setter of PageSource
```

---

```
North.java
...
@command
public void linkClicked(){
   // access main object and call main.setPageSource("content2.zul") (how to do this ?)
}
```

---

---

Now if a `http` request come for main.zul then instance of Main and North will be created and is there anyway i can access Main object ?

Is there any thing like `ZKcontext` , where i can ask for session scope instances ?

Comment: I don't follow your question. You say "a _request_ to main.zul will create _session scope_ instances..". What sort of _request_ are you referring to? When you say _session scope_, do you mean you put these Java objects in the [`Session`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Session.html)? You show where `north.zul` is referenced, but where does `North.java` come into play?

Comment: request is a http request... no i am not putting any object in session... i think there should be some session which keep this objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post a global command from your `onClick` event in `north.zul`:

`onClick="@global-command('switchContent', file='content2.zul')"`

In your `Main.java` you listen for this global command:

```
@GlobalCommand
@NotifyChange("pageSource")
public void switchContent(@BindingParam("file") String file) {
  setPageSource(file);
}
```

Comment: Brawo!!! you made my day....just to confirm there is no other way to communicate between viewModels of different view right ?....

Comment: Not that i know of. That's the way to go ^^